Spring Data JPA re-use query as a subquery
I have a query
@Query("""SELECT x FROM X x WHERE ...""")
Object getSomething(); 

in the same repository I have another method which basically includes the above select as a subquery
@Query("""SELECT y FROM ( {here} ) y WHERE ...""")
Object doSomethingAfter();

Is it possible to re-use the above query in some way? Currently the only solution I've found is basically making a constant string and just re-using it but it just seems like there should be a better way to do what I'm doing.
Also it's a native query, but I couldn't get it to work as a HQL query as well. I think I had an update as well instead of the 2nd select but I guess the idea here is the same. This is just the simplest example I could come up with. So I'm interested in a solution if it only works with HQL

If you often need the data from this subquery in different places, perhaps one solution is to have a view directly in your database (which you can also optimise).

It's just this one place. I was interested if there was a better way to do what I'm doing
